# How can I display taken picture saved in data/data/

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I do not know how to open saved image and display it into gridView.

I make an intent to take a photo:

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null && file != null) {
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

And file is saved in /data/data/package/files/...
But when I tried to open file and create a bitmap it always return null.

```
    try {
        is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(f));
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);}
```

even if I use  decodeFile method() I still have a null bitmap.
Files exist in data/data/ ... I checked it.

My question is: how can I get dispaly taken image?

Comment: means u want to take all gallery pic in ur app is it u mean

Comment: Yes I prefers to save pics in data\data than in gallery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can't store Pictures caught on camera directly on your app memory, you should write it to `sdcard` and copy it to your space and delete the original. Because camera is a another app that has no privillege to write on your apps storage space. You can check that if you have root permissions.

If you specify your app memory for camera intent it will always return `NULL`

You can read this for  [WORLD_WRITEABLE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/B4Z6awdZsXc)